# How can I plot all elements of a cell in different colours?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a cell of size 8, with this structure:

```
 Columns 1 through 4

    [172x3 double]    [53x3 double]    [70x3 double]    [57x3 double]

  Columns 5 through 8

    [55x3 double]    [43x3 double]    [104x3 double]    [46x3 double]
```

Every cell element is a matrix containing 3D points for each row. I want to plot every cell element on the same plot, but with different colours. Is there a simple way to do this in MATLAB?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would like to bring it to your attention that it is not the friendliest gesture to delete a question that someone took the time to answer properly. I will assume you deleted your newer question because you realized that your error was trivial, and you'd probably be right (and no harm done). Just be warned that after a number of deleted questions (to which answers have been given), you might be banned from asking new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATLAB [`axes`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) object has the amazing `'ColorOrder'` property, which controls what color the plots you add will have. The default color order only has 7 colors, which look like this:

[image: color order] (Source: [Mathworks](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html))

You can either set the entire color order to something different, or just add e.g. black as last color:

```
fig = figure(1);
ax = axes;
set(ax, 'ColorOrder', [get(ax,'ColorOrder'); 0,0,0])
```

Now you can set [`hold`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) to on, so you can call `plot` multiple times and the current plots are retained:

```
hold(ax, 'on')
```

and finally plot your data with [`plot3`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) and the `'.'` option, which plots only the points, and no lines. You could do that in a `for` loop, or even simpler by using [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to call `plot3` for every cell:

```
cellfun(@(x) plot3(x(:,1), x(:,2), x(:,3), '.'), myCell)
```

And that's it. A small example:

```
% Create sample data
myCell = {0.1*randn(100,3), 0.1*randn(100,3)+[zeros(100,1),ones(100,1),zeros(100,1)],...
    0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),zeros(100,1),zeros(100,1)], 0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),ones(100,1),zeros(100,1)],...
    0.1*randn(100,3)+[zeros(100,1),zeros(100,1),ones(100,1)], 0.1*randn(100,3)+[zeros(100,1),ones(100,1),ones(100,1)],...
    0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),zeros(100,1),ones(100,1)], 0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),ones(100,1),ones(100,1)]}

% Plot
fig = figure(1);
ax = axes;
set(ax, 'ColorOrder', [get(ax,'ColorOrder'); 0,0,0])
hold(ax, 'on')
cellfun(@(x) plot3(x(:,1), x(:,2), x(:,3), '.'), myCell)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Have you tried rotating the plot using the corresponding button in the GUI? I guess the plot is really 3D, but only 2 dimensions are visible..

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use the color palettes provided by MATLAB. For example

```
myCell = {0.1*randn(100,3), 0.1*randn(100,3)+[zeros(100,1),ones(100,1),zeros(100,1)],...
0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),zeros(100,1),zeros(100,1)], 0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),ones(100,1),zeros(100,1)],...
0.1*randn(100,3)+[zeros(100,1),zeros(100,1),ones(100,1)], 0.1*randn(100,3)+[zeros(100,1),ones(100,1),ones(100,1)],...
0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),zeros(100,1),ones(100,1)], 0.1*randn(100,3)+[ones(100,1),ones(100,1),ones(100,1)]}


col = jet(length(myCell))

for i=1:length(myCell)
    plot3(myCell{i}(:,1),myCell{i}(:,2),myCell{i}(:,3), 'Color', col(i,:), 'LineStyle', '.')
    hold on
end
```

If you want specific colors, you can enter the col matrix manually.